# show overlapping volume of two objects in different color in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have two overlapping objects in my scene in THREE.js. I was wondering how I can show the overlapping volume of the two objects in different color or texture? 
or at least the combination of the two objects with different colors, showing another color? for example if the two objects are in red and blue, the overlapping volume shows the overlapping color which is purple. Thank you in advance! something like this:

[image]

Comment: Quick and dirty - Have you tried setting the material parameters for each of the two objects as: transparent: true, opacity: 0.6

Comment: thanks, actually, this works when I change the renderOrder to 1 for one of them. but the problem is one of my objects needs to be 100 percent opaque!

Comment: Hmmm, I'm struggling to understand how you would expect to "see" the internal volume of a 3D object whose surface is opaque.  If you posted a screenshot or provided more of a description of what you are trying to achieve, it might help.

Comment: Thanks! I have added an image. this is what I want to do :)

Comment: Can you show a live example to demonstrate your issue? Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akmcv7Lh/) you can edit.

Comment: @Hesamoy And setting the big red block as transparent: false while setting the little blue block as transparent: true, opacity: 0.6 (or so) doesn't give you the result you want?

Comment: @pprchsvr I did as you told, and it does not give me the result, the overlapping volume does not shown at all. I cannot see the overlapping volume like the image I uploaded above! I am now trying to create a live demo.

Comment: @WestLangley Please see the live demo http://jsfiddle.net/akmcv7Lh/18/ . As you can see, the overlapping volume between the two cubes cannot be seen. 
but I want something as shown in the image added above. Thank you.

Comment: Here is a start -- but only a start. You will learn a lot about transparency in webGL by working on this. http://jsfiddle.net/akmcv7Lh/19/

Comment: Thank you very much WestLangley and pprchsvr.

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider using boolean operations by implementing something like [ThreeCSG.js](http://%22ThreeCSG.js).

Lets say you have two meshes `cube_one` and `cube_two`. Then you can do:

```
cube_one_bsp = new ThreeBSP( cube_one );
cube_two_bsp = new ThreeBSP( cube_two );
cube_three_bsp = cube_one_bsp.intersect( cube_two_bsp );
```

and now you can give `cube_three` any material when converting it back to a `THREE.Mesh` using the `toMesh` method:

```
mesh = cube_three_bsp.toMesh( material );
```

and now you have the intersected object as a `THEE.Mesh` with your custom material...